# Open Close Specific Divs On Mobile Dropdown Menu

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

Trying to create a mobile menu with sub menus which open and close upon click.

Currently the trigger open and closes all of the hidden sub menus and not just the specific sub menu related to the parent link.

The ul.sub-menu is hidden and want this to open and close when click on the .item-toggle and only open that specific sub menu.

How can this be fixed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("ul.sub-menu").hide();
 $(".icon-toggle").click (function(){
 $("ul.sub-menu").toggle();
 });
});

    <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1788" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1788">
            <a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-cigarettes/e-cigarette-starter-kit/">E-Cigarette Starter Kits</a>
           </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1740" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1740">
            <a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-cigarettes/e-cigarette-advanced-kits/">E-Cigarette Advanced Kits</a>
           </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
<li id="menu-item-804" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-804"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/mods/">Mods <i class="icon-toggle"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-799" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-799"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/">E-Liquids <i class="icon-toggle"></i></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1733" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1733"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/cloudy-reef/">Cloudy Reef</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1735" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1735"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/vaper-crew/">Vaper Crew</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1734" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1734"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/tempest-premium/">Tempest Premium</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-841" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-841"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/aniseed/">Aniseed</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-842" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-842"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/desert/">Dessert</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-843" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-843"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/sweets/">Sweets</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-844" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-844"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/vanilla/">Vanilla</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-845" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-845"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/tobacco/">Tobacco</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-846" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-846"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/fruit/">Fruit</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-847" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-847"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-liquids/mint/">Mint / Icy</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-800" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-800"><a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/tanksclearomizers/">Tanks &amp; Clearomizers <i class="icon-toggle"></i></a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7akc5f7y/10/

Comment: The code, specifically the jQuery, in the JSFiddle you linked in your post is different to the code in the body of your post. Which are you trying to use?

Comment: `$(this)` is an `i` and doesn't have an id, either

Comment: @ZacWebb sorry still playing in the fiddle - original code is back now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite difficult to understand your code, so I have created a new environment to explain how to go about what you want to achieve.

Using the `.next()` method in jQuery, you can select the next element that meets the parameter defined, therefore when you click on a category on your website, it should find the next `<ul>` (below it) and display that.

See an example on what you want to achieve:

```js
$('.cat').click(function(){
 $(this).next('.sub').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 35px;
}

.cat {
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sub {
  display: none;
}

.sub li {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="cat">Category</li>
  <ul class="sub">
    <li>Item in category</li>
    <li>Item in category</li>
    <li>Item in category</li>
  </ul>
  
  <li class="cat">Category</li>
  <ul class="sub">
    <li>Item in category</li>
    <li>Item in category</li>
    <li>Item in category</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: i have tried this and no luck - maybe as the triggers I'm using are not directly next to each other, as the i class is wrapped inside the a tag
    <a href="http://vapour-shack.com/cat/e-cigarettes/">E-Cigarettes <i class="icon-toggle"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-1788"